# Is JavaFX supposed to supersede Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx

I am used to Swing programming and have heard about JavaFX. Is it supposed to replace Swing as the preferred platform for writing desktop applications in Java?

To put it in another way, should I choose JavaFX for my new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes JavaFX is replacing Swing.**

See also official documentation of Oracle:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6

> **Is JavaFX replacing Swing as the new client UI library for Java SE?**
>
> Yes. However, Swing will remain part of the Java SE specification for
> the foreseeable future, and therefore included in the JRE. While we
> recommend developers to leverage JavaFX APIs as much as possible when
> building new applications, it is possible to extend a Swing
> application with JavaFX, allowing for a smoother transition.

See also SO posts:

- [Swing vs JavaFx for desktop applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694948/swing-vs-javafx-for-desktop-applications)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing (OLD)

Comment: …as much as an add-on can replace a built-in feature.