# difference between animation using swing and animation using javafx

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have to create a window transition animation for android (like the one when closing an app. It fades away and another comes in from a corner) on java. I have heard that animating with swing is a bit more complicated than with javafx. So will I face any problems while making programs using only swing or is there anything I cannot do using swing but could do using javafx? I would prefer using swing as I am familiar with it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694948/swing-vs-javafx-for-desktop-applications

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273822

Comment: Swing has been around for 15+ years, has strong community of experienced developers writing code in production environments. JavaFX is the (newer) kid on the block, which has less experienced developers (with the API) and hasn't seen as much production exposure (you can do a search for job postings for Swing and JavaFX, while Swing is decline, JavaFX has been very quite). JavaFX certainly has been built from the ground up with things like animation in mind (it was targeted as a Flash killer, but HTML 5 pretty much killed both).

Comment: If you need "sliding" style animations, I suggest you have a look at [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) and [Sliding Layout](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/09/new-library-sliding-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

JavaFx is better to use as it is having better properties.
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/10-differences-between-javafx-and-swing.html