# Is JavaFX still a better option to create GUI applications in Java?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

JavaFX is a very power full way of creating GUI applications for the developers who are familiar with Java, but none of any updates happened for javaFX in java newer versions. and in Java 13, some of the previous features are not included.

as a beginner should I learn javaFX or Swing or any other way to create java GUI applications

Comment: As someone who used and somewhat liked JavaFX, no I wouldn't recommend learning it any more. Every GUI I write these days uses React

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swing vs JavaFx for desktop applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694948/swing-vs-javafx-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: @Michael Apples and Oranges. React is for writing Web UIs. JavaFX and Swing are for writing Desktop UIs.

Comment: @Andreas And what does your browser run on? A desktop. Every Java based desktop app I write these days is a Spring Boot web server with a web front end. Even if it runs locally. IMO that is the best way to write Java desktop apps right now. JavaFX is bad in comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to create Java Gui programs that run on local machines, JavaFX is still the way to go. For starters, I can highly recommend the [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) which is now customized and released by Gluon.
Eventhough JavaFX does no longer come with the JRE, its still [Open Source in development](https://openjfx.io/).

These are just my two cents, you might get other opinions on that topic.