# Starting on JavaFX - JavaFX version and "development patterns" questions

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am planning on starting the development of a desktop app, but until now, for me, desktop = swing. I did a little research about it and found myself under some questions:

1. I found that there are a lot of JavaFX versions:

   - There is JavaFX 1.0 that people say is old and outdated;
   - There is JavaFX 2.X that is very good;
   - And now JavaFX 8 (is this correct?);

   But even with the most recent NetBeans IDE version (8.0) with JDK 8 (1.8.0), when I create a JavaFX application, it starts using JavaFX 2.2 – Is JavaFX 8 really a new JavaFX version or people say it just because they use JavaFX 2.X with JDK 8?
2. Another question about versions, will applications developed in a version X of JavaFX be compatible with higher versions? Just like a swing application, where if you developed an application in Java 5, it would work even on Java 8.
3. About development patterns, more specifically about layout creation, I noticed there are two ways for creating layouts: By just coding it in Java, and by creating XML files (FXML) with a Java Class as a controller (More MVC approach) just like a JSF application. Which one should I choose? What are the pros and cons of each one?

Comment: I have not dived very deep into it but JavaFX is my preferred library for Java GUI development now. With Java 8 it is now part of the JRE without extra steps to deploy so the development/deployment side of things is much less complicated. It does have modern GUI elements, and perhaps the most important, a modern/native looking file browser. Just give it a try, it is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Welcome to the world of JavaFX

*I am not sure why you are facing such an issue of JavaFX 2.2 with JDK 1.8 because JDK 8 has JavaFX 8 in it and it must be used by default.*

Just to give a quick introduction on JavaFX and how it is different from Swing. Please follow the following points:

1. Instead of following the legacy of building the view/UI in Java code and messing your functional codes with views, you get the opportunity of separating the view with the functionality using the [**FXML**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm) introduced in JavaFX 2.0+
2. JavaFX has powerful **CSS** integration which allows you to decorate the view, which was **absent in Swing**.
3. The development is quicker, as you have [**SceneBuilder**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/Java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) to back you.

For more differences on Swing and JavaFX please follow (though the answers are old and many things have changed. **JavaFX has become bigger and better!**)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/JavaFX-or-swing

[JavaFX 2 vs Swing for a pure Windows desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587713/JavaFX-2-vs-swing-for-a-pure-windows-desktop-app)

**Difference between JavaFX 1+, 2+ and 8+**

1. JavaFX 1+ was basically a scripting language called as JavaFX script, which was very different from the Java language.
2. JavaFX 2.0 changed the face of JavaFX. All of JavaFX API was now available as pure Java API. FXML was also introduced during this phase in JavaFX!
3. JavaFX 8.0 leads to a new face of JavaFX where JavaFX is accepted as an integral part of **Java 8**.

**Compatibility** - All JavaFX application is **forward compliance**, i.e. *JavaFX 2.0+ is compatible with Java 7, 8 and above*. Though applications made using **JavaFX 8 is not compatible with Java 7**.

[JavaFX 1.3 support has been killed from Java 1.7.](https://blogs.oracle.com/Java/entry/eoling_java_se_6_javafx)

**Development Patterns**

1. JavaFX gives a chance to build your application using your choice – i.e. use the **legacy method of building the view using pure Java** or use **FXML**.
2. JavaFX strictly follows MVC pattern, separating your view and its events. The views are created using **FXML** and the controllers are Java files.

[From Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/JavaFX/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm)

**From a Model View Controller (MVC) perspective, the FXML file that contains the description of the user interface is the view. The controller is a Java class, optionally implementing the Initializable class, which is declared as the controller for the FXML file. The model consists of domain objects, defined on the Java side, that you connect to the view through the controller.**

Some more information and **pro's for FXML**, please follow:

[Which is better way of programming in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828398/1759128)

Comment: So, if i create a JavaFX app using JDK8, i am using JavaFX8, not JavaFX 2, right?

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. Do you know why lots of new components are only supported in JFX8 and not in JFX2? I have to use java 7 and I don't understand why they dropped support to jfx2.

Comment: @Rafaesp Its just how a feature evolves. JavaFX 8 had a new UI (modena) and many bug fixes. You should think about using Java 8 instead of Java 7 if JavaFX is an important part of your software.