# Node.js VS. JavaFX for simple client application (prints out message from server)

Tags: node.js, sockets, javafx, client-server

### Application in question

**Server side**

A server, written in Node.js, will be handling some requests and sending text messages that the client application needs to print out for the user.

**Client Side**

Client will receive message from server and print it out. The client side will be running in a PC.

### Problem

My colleague and I are questioning what technology is best to use for the client application, seeing how simple it will be. All it has to do is have  a nice GUI that print out whatever message it receives from the server.

### Candidates for client side application

**Node.js**

One possibility is to build the client side application with Node.js, html, css and javascript. The main advantage of for this is the fact that the server is built with the same technology, making communication via socket quite easy. There will be no need for *polling* from the client side, since they will always be connected via a socket and whenever the server receives a message, it will push it to the client, who will act accordingly.

**JavaFX**

This would be the other possibility, because the GUI will have animation, and it needs to be as smooth as possible. The problem here is the lack of experience with JavaFX, and how well it will perform in a constant connection with the server.

---

I would really appreciate any insight from someone with experience.

Comment: How do you wish to deploy the application?

Comment: It will be deployed on a single PC.

Comment: That makes the decision easier. If you'd deploy it to a 100 clients, you wouldn't want to mess with Oracle's installation nightmare where Java versions are outdated, browsers block Java and the likes. If it's only a single client, I'd rather say choose what you're familiar with and what gives you the quickest result.

Comment: Here is a sample [JavaFX based solution](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test) which uses WebSockets for client/server communication.  It is best to make your own decision on technology choices rather than canvas opinions; you know the most about your target app and your skill set, so you are the best qualified person to make a choice.

Comment: @jewelsea Quite appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Lack of experience with JavaFX

This is not going to be an issue. If you have some experience with Java, you are good to go. Even if you have no experience, don't be disheartened, as [Oracle has very rich documentation to get you started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

Here are some points in support of JavaFX:

- JavaFX comes with a drag and drop instant UI tool called [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/Java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html). Once you start using it, you will never look back. The output of this tool are files called **FXMLs** and can be termed as view of the JavaFX application.
- [JavaFX supports CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). Almost all nodes on JavaFX can be designed using JavaFX CSS, though the CSS used on JavaFX is different from the standard CSS, but you will get hold of it quite soon. ;)
- [JavaFX UI (FXMLs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm) can seamlessly be plugged into your code using controllers, which means one developer can work on the UI, while someone else works on the business logic.
- JavaFX can create easy [distribution packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/), using which you can create different distribution packages (installers) aimed for different OS's with just one click on the build file. For example, options `EXE and MSI` for windows, `DEB` for Linux and `APP` for Mac OS X.
- Get the power of Multi-Threaded environment.
- Runs on Java Runtime, which is present in almost all the systems throughout the world. The user may not have to install a runtime in order to run the JavaFX application.

Coming to the second part of your question on **constant connection with the server**, you will have no problem with it because JavaFX runs on JVM, which is an age old medium tested for socket connections. [Here is a nice tutorial on Socket communication.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

***Though I would prefer using JSON over HTTP, instead of sockets to do this.***

A link that you want to go through:

[Starting on JavaFX - JavaFX version and "development patterns" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712382/starting-on-javafx-javafx-version-and-development-patterns-questions/23712845#23712845)

**Note:** *The user has no experience with **node.js**, so you may consider the advantages and compare it with what you have with a node.js client.*

Comment: Quite thorough, appreciate it.

Comment: I have a question though, with JavaFX I would have to be constantly polling for new data from the server, correct? Or is it possible for the JavaFX to have an open, permanent connection with the server (Node.js io.socket style).

Comment: The [Java Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) keeps listening to a host and port, once created, unless you close the Socket connection. You can find all you want to know about [Java Sockets here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). I highly recommend to run the examples given in the link.

Comment: I'm curious: What happens on a network interruption? Will the connection be automatically re-opened?

Comment: AFAIK, during network interruption, it won't attempt *automatic reconnection*. It will most probably throw a [`java.net.SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html) and exit.